# How to replace element with ExtJs ajax responseText

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, extjs, extjs4

I'm trying to convert the jquery ajax to Extjs and eliminate the use for jquery library.

But here's the problem...

After loading the ajax response with Ext.Ajax.request the scripts from the ajaxed page don't get trigger.

jQuery Ajax function:

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '@Url.Content("~/Test/Header/")',
            success: function (response) {
                $("#header").replaceWith(response);
            }
        });
    });
```

The code above works perfectly with the ajax content displaying properly and all the javascript get executed properly.

Here's the Extjs version of the ajax request:

```
        Ext.onDocumentReady(function () {
        Ext.Ajax.request({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '@Url.Content("~/Test/Header/")',
            success: function (response) {
                Ext.get('header').dom.outerHTML = response.responseText;
            }
        });
    });
```

The code above works fine in retrieving the response content, but when I replace the existing 'div' with the responseText, the javascripts from the response page doesn't get trigger.

I suspect that this is because I'm not replacing the element correctly.

So when I try using the jQuery version of the element replace, it works fine.

**My question is, what's the proper way for Extjs to replace a 'div'?**

I've tried a couple ways, and none of them works...

**A better way to rephrase my question is... what is the Extjs equivalent of:**

```
$("#header").replaceWith(response);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

jQuery:

`$("#header").replaceWith(response);`

extjs:

```
Ext.get('header').replaceWith(response);
//note: no pound sign
```

Source:

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.dom.Element-method-replaceWith

The API docs miss some things here and there, but overall, an amazing reference. Enjoy!

Comment: Thanks @tuespetre, but I've tried that before and it doesn't yield the correct result.  What's being replace is `" responseXML="">`, which I'm not sure why that.  My understanding is that replaceWith takes a String/HTMLElement/Ext.dom.AbstractElement/Object, but response does not hold the htmlcontent.  **response.responseText** does, but if I replace the element with the responseText the javascript doesn't get executed.  This is my problem.  JQuery's ajax method have none of this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same problem. The solution is:

```
var workspaceCenter = Ext.fly('workspaceCenter');
workspaceCenter.load({
    url     : url ,
    params  : params,
    scripts : true,            <------ this is the trick
    callback : function() {
        Ext.getBody().unmask();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Dmitry, I've tried setting scripts to true as part of the ajax request, but I'm not seeing any difference.  I might be putting it in the wrong place.

Comment: The matter is, it doesn't work with Ext.Ajax.request (if I understand you correctly), but it is when using component.load().